# Hom set as a vector space isomorphic to direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space of countable dimension over the field $K$. How to show as $K$-vector spaces, $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $V$ and $V$?

Comment: how is this related to homological algebra?

Comment: In fact, I made a mistake. It should be $V \oplus V \cong V$. Then $T \cong Hom_K(V,V) \cong Hom_K(V \oplus V,V) \cong Hom_K(V,V) \oplus Hom_K(V,V) \cong T \oplus T$

Comment: so in General, a free module on a set of n elements may be isomorphic to a free module on a set of m elements, where m is not equal to n. Maybe it could be categorized into a question in module theory. But Hagen Von Eitzen gave a nice counter example for the original question after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because they are not. To easily see this, consider the special case that $K$ is finite (or countably infinite) and $\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$  is a basis of $V$. Then $V$ is countable (as a set) and so is $V\oplus V$.
But $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ is not countable because for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$ we can definie a linear map $f\colon V\to V$ by $$f(v_i)=\begin{cases}v_i&\text{if }i\in A\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and these are pairwise distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe want to show that $$Hom(V,V) \cong V^* \otimes V?$$ This result is quite nice. However, I have not checked if it holds for infinite diminsional vectorspaces.